# Javascript function assignment using eval

Tags: javascript, eval, lvalue

I am having trouble reassigning functions. I want to assign a previously defined function, `drawScene` a different method.

```
function fSwap(funcName, code) {
    eval(funcName) = eval(code);
}
fSwap("drawScene", "function drawScene() { /* Do something */ }");
```

I feel like this should work, but for some reason `eval(funcName)` is not an lvalue and it returns the error `ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side`. All the more puzzling is:

```
var a = function test() {return 0;};
alert(a === eval("a"));
eval("a") = function test() {return 1;};
```

Gives an alert with `true` but does not let me assign to the function `a`.

My only guess is that eval() does not return lvalues for security reasons. If so, how can I implement fSwap() such that it takes in two strings and assigns the code to the given function name?

Comment: Why not use `drawScene = function()  { /* Do something */ };`, without needing eval at all?

Comment: I want to use strings input from the user to assign to functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should instead use a callback function. You can do that like this:

```
function fSwap(funcName, callback) {
    window[funcName] = callback;
}
fSwap("drawScene", function drawScene() { /* Do something */ });
```

---

To answer your question directly, what's going wrong is that you're assigning a value to an evaluated piece of code. That won't work. What would work would be:

```
function fSwap(funcName, code) {
    eval(funcName+' = '+code);
}
```

but please do not do it this way. The other way, using callback functions, is much cleaner. It's almost always better not to use `eval` whenever it's not absolutely required to use it. (According to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21649928/1256925#comment32720603_21649928), apparently it is absolutely required to use strings, so do use this piece of code).

Comment: both arguments of fSwap are strings, will your first code snippet still work?

Comment: @JDong the second block of code (the one that does use `eval`) would indeed work with 2 strings being entered. The first code would require the second parameter to be a function though. If it is absolutely required that both parameters are strings, use the second code. That would work.

Comment: I unfortunately have to use eval() then. If there is a better way to take a user-input function and assign that to code, I'm still all ears.

Comment: @JDong, for such cases (when function's source code is external) eval is ok. Just don't misuse it when it's on your side and you can write it as a regular function.

Comment: @JDong if you're running code that's provided by users, then you will need to use eval, but keep in mind that you should **only ever use this for the user himself**. Never let user-provided code run for any user other than the user himself, to prevent **major** security issues.

Comment: Hah, yea was waiting for the timeout on the checkmark. This is for a 100% client-side webGL simulator, so no XSS here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party but the following should work for taking a user-input string as a function.

```
var foo=function(){alert("foo");};
foo();//alerts 'foo'

function fSwap(funcName, fn) {
    eval("newfunc = "+fn);
    window[funcName] = newfunc;
}
fSwap("foo","function(){alert('bar');}");

foo();//alerts 'bar'
```

DEMO: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/fahal/1/edit?js,output)

Comment: Is the `window[funcName] = newfunc;` necessary? I feel like `eval(funcName+' = '+code);` is probably a better solution because it doesn't create a temp variable.

Comment: @JDong yes, you're right. In my head I was thinking that using `window[funcName]` would restrict the user to only replacing a function that already exists. After checking, I realise that was bollocks ;)